# How to INSERT/UPDATE a relational record that may exist based of the existence of a different record

Tags: mysql, database, insert, sql-update

A have a relational table which relates tags to photos:

```
table: tag_photo_x
photo_id
tag_id
status

PRIMARY INDEX: photo_id,tag_id
```

I'm in the process of merging some tags together as they are pretty similar (ie: landscape, landscapes). So, a photo may or may not already have a record for both tags.

In this example, I want to use 1 query to go through all the relations for the tag 'landscapes' and insert a record for 'landscape'.

My problem is that I can't get my head around how to write a single query which will insert the 'landscape' record based of the existence of the 'landscapes' record and 'on duplicate key', update status = 1.

I have quite a few photos and tags i'll be doing this for, thus the need to try to do this in a single query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to insert `landscape` where there is `landscape`, then just do an `insert`:

```
insert into tag_photo_x(photo_id, tag_id)
    select photo_id, 'landscape'
    from tag_photo_x tp
    where tag_id = 'landscapes' and
          not exists (select 1
                      from tag_photo_x tp2
                      where tp.photo_id = tp2.photo_id and
                            tp2.tag_id = 'landscape'
                     );
```

You can then delete the `landscapes` tag, if you like.